# Is Microsoft Prism alive and active?

Tags: microsoft, frameworks

I've been doing a lot of reading these last two days on [Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx), but the thing I'm still not very sure of is what does the future look like for it? I know that version 4.1 was just released a few months ago, but besides Microsoft's own documentation, I haven't found many blog posts written in the last year on the subject, most of what I find is 2009-2010.

It definitely looks interesting but the learning curve seems to be a bit steep and I wouldn't want to embark if it's going to become obsolete in the near future. Anyone has any insight on this?

Comment: I never heard of this until today.

Comment: -1. I think you answered your own question with "I know that version 4.1 was just released a few months ago". Sounds active to me. Perhaps the question you asked isn't what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is still active, I mean is not the most popular MS project that does not mean that is inactive, in general when a considerable big company Google, MS, Apple or organization like Apache will stop development of certain project they will make it clear month if not a year before. That being said in the [official Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) there is no sign of being abandon or dropped either. Although I am not a MS fan or ever heard of Prism seems like a solid unknown project.

If you go to [this Codeplex](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) site:

```
future releases

Prism 4.1 targetting Silverlight 5. Go here to learn about future releases.
Prism 4.5 targetting .NET 4.5.
```

Comment: I wrote a long comment about why PRISM isn't very popular, and then realised I was getting completely mixed up between PRISM and UNITY. Perhaps that confusion is indicative of why these projects are not enjoying as much popularity as their counterparts.

Comment: I hadn't seen that "future releases" bit, that's nice to know.